# Debugging in a particular order

Tags: bash

I want to automatically specify the files that I want debugging mode to be enabled.

```
# Define files needing debugging
files_to_debug=(
  "${trkrc}/navaid.rc"
  "${trkrc}/buranex.rc"
)

# Enable debugging for specific file sources
for file in "${files_to_debug[@]}"; do
  set -xv
  source "$file"
  set +xv
done

# Continue sourcing other files without debugging
source "${trkrc}/marinex.rc"
source "${trkrc}/firefly.rc"
source "${trkrc}/comseq.rc"
source "${trkrc}/comint.rc"
```

But I want to source my files in a particular order.

```
  source "${trkrc}/marinex.rc"
  source "${trkrc}/firefly.rc"
  source "${trkrc}/navaid.rc"
  source "${trkrc}/buranex.rc"

  source "${trkrc}/comseq.rc"
  source "${trkrc}/comint.rc"
```

A possibility that could have a good chance is to associate with each file a numeric value, `1` for applying `set -xv` before and `set +xv` after the source command' and just sourcing when `0` is encountered.

The script could generate the following `debug-config` file

```
0 marinex.rc
0 firefly.rc
0 navaid.rc
0 buranex.rc
    
0 comseq.rc
0 comint.rc
```

The user can then change the value from `0` to `1` on those files ho wants debugging.

I would be grateful for assistance in implementing this thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could make functions like

```
d() { set -xv; }
nd() { set +xv; }
```

and then call `d` or `nd` before each `source`:

```
nd; source "${trkrc}/marinex.rc"
nd; source "${trkrc}/firefly.rc"
 d; source "${trkrc}/navaid.rc"
 d; source "${trkrc}/buranex.rc"
nd; source "${trkrc}/comseq.rc"
nd; source "${trkrc}/comint.rc"
nd
```

This isn't exactly what you had there with the array, but avoids repeating the filenames.

Of course you could also make the combined function:

```
dsource() {
    set -xv
    source "$1"
    set +xv
}
```

but sourcing from inside a function might change the meaning of the sourced code. (At least `declare` would create local variables within a function, and would need to be changed to `declare -g` to create globals instead.)

Comment: I would like the files to be debugged to be user defined, the debug operation to be automatically inserted, and the order kept intact.  My intention is to have a debug session that does not require one to change the actual code, although such thing could be done if a more focused debugging would be needed.

Comment: I wight be getting somewhere with your `dsource` routine.

Comment: I might be getting somewhere with your `dsource` routine.  You are absolutely right with your comment about local variables in functions.  Is sourcing from a function, something that is rarely done for script libraries ?

Comment: Perhaps I can show a list of files where the user can decide, `1` for debug, `0` or `-1` for no debug.  Can store filenames in a file in the correct order.